# GRUB2 Makefile (Makefile.core.def)

Tags: makefile, grub

In grub2/grub-core's Makefile.core.def,

```
module = {
    name = regexp;
    common = commands/regexp.c;
    common = commands/wildcard.c
    ldadd = libgnulib.a;
    cflags = '$(CFLAGS_POSIX) $(CFLAGS_GNULIB)';
    cppflags = '$(CPPFLAGS_POSIX) $(CPPFLAGS_GNULIB)'
};
```

What does ldadd do?  Where does libgnulib.a live? I tried to search for libgnulib.a in the grub directory but I couldn't find it.  I also tried to search online but couldn't find any info.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Did you try searching for `AutoGen definitions` on the internet? The first hit for me seems fairly relevant to that file and its contents. https://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/manual/html_node/Definitions-File.html

Comment: Your question on the grub-devel mailing lists suggests this may in fact be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396711/grub-bootloader-with-shared-library-support.

Answer (score 1):

The construct you are referring to actually went away in the upstream project last November, with [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/commit/grub-core/Makefile.core.def?id=469021b4b3f93e74b92cc3ef152c3f0723c366b1). The `regexp` module now simply includes `gnulib/regex.c` directly.

Before then, it was a library generated as part of the build, and put into the `grub-core` directory. The `ldadd` directive simply causes the generated Makefile to add the specified library to the link step for the current module.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I see library = {
  name = libgnulib.a;
  common = gnulib/regex.c;
  cflags = '$(CFLAGS_POSIX) $(CFLAGS_GNULIB)';
  cppflags = '$(CPPFLAGS_POSIX) $(CPPFLAGS_GNULIB)';
};  Why is the "gnulib/regex.c" used for the common?

Comment: 'common' simply means build and include in module for all target platforms. Certain modules with either processor or firmware architecture specific bits also contain source files included per architecture; for example the 'linux' module.

Comment: You mentioned the libgnulib.a was generated as part of the build and put into the grub-core directory, but I cannot find it there.  I tried find command and couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: No - like I said, it no longer exists in the upstream version of GRUB.

Comment: We are still using the older version, and looks like we won't be updating for a while.

Comment: Then I must say that I am most perplexed, since when I reset to the version of grub where libgnulib.a is still explicitly included and built, I get a grub-core/libgnulib.a generated. Regardless, it sounds like the actual problem you are trying to solve is not actually related to your question. I would recommend you post a new question describing what you are trying to do, and what problems you are encountering while doing it.